# How should I write my control file which is used to load text file data into Mysql table using sqlldr command?

Tags: oracle, etl, sql-loader

I have to load data from a text file into a table. My data in text file is delimited by '`,`' and each item is present in double quotes (i.e., `""`).

For example, data in the text file is like below:

```
"1009","John","NY","USA"
"1010","Ron","AZ","USA"
```

How should I write my control file in order not to include the double quotes (i.e., `""`) while loading data into the table.

Comment: Show your preliminary work, how you read the data and how you tried to parse it. Also, the problem seems a text-formatting problem rather ran a sql/plsql one. If so, consider updating the tags for better response. Thanks.

Comment: SQL*Loader means "Oracle". you said you want to load data into "MySQL" table. I might be wrong, but - that utility loads data into Oracle, not MySQL. So, what do you really use & have?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table structure is like the following:

```
create table someTable(
    colA number,
    colB varchar2(100),
    colC varchar2(100),
    colD varchar2(100)
)
```

You can use the SQLLoader with a control file like:

```
OPTIONS(skip=0) 
load data
infile "data.txt"
append into TABLE someTable
fields
terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
(
  colA "to_number(:colA)", /* here you can use a format for numbers, if any */
  colB,
  colC,
  colD
)
```